# Get current Timestamp and concatenate with string in yml file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

Setting up a yml based azure build pipeline for which publishing artifacts require timestamp based name. Trying to do something like this

```
'ArtifactName' + currentTimeStamp
```

How can this be done in an yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you expected result:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "Setting up the date time for build variable"
      $date=$(Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd-Hmmss)
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentTimeStamp]$date"
    displayName: 'Geting timestamp'

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      artifact: 'ArtifactName-$(currentTimeStamp)'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I know in the second option, why is the variable declared as mydate and while concatenation it is currentTimeStamp

Comment: My mistake ;) it should be `currentTimeStamp`.

Comment: 'ArtifactName' + $(currentTimeStamp) gives an error 'While parsing a block maping, did not find expected key.'

Answer (score 0):

You can set the build name in the first line of yml script.

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)-$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)
```

See tokens here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

And then set the artifactName concatenating the $(Build.BuildNumber) that represents the name set before

```
    artifactName: 'ArtifactName-$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```